# Contactform7 not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

My contact7 form is not working, none of the functionality is working, tha ajax and after post validation aren't working. I checked the console for a conflict but there's none. The html is the same i've used on other forms.

This is my form:

disennio.com/clients/lunata/reservaciones/

Comment: The JS for the plugin isn't loading, and your form is missing an action. How are you including this form on the page?

Comment: I used the echo do_shortcode() function. I've had issues before with the js not loading but even the after post notifications aren't working.

Comment: I double check and yes, it was not loading the js, no it's loading it but the issue remains. http://i.imgur.com/7feCFfC.png

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to manually insert the form code on your page. Instead, you'll need to use Contact Form 7's insert a form feature while you are editing that particular page in the WordPress dashboard.

Comment: I'm not manually inserting the form, i used the do_shortcode() function with the proper id, the form isn't working even if i use the html from the plugin page examples.

Comment: I migrated from CF7 to Gravity Forms a few years ago. It resolved a lot of issues that I was having with forms.

Comment: I'll give it a try on any future project, i like CF7 but it's behavior on some servers it's unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

It was mobile plugin related issue, will find another solution for mobile validations. Sorry.